# When does a keli not require immersion?

Tags: tevilas-keilim-dipping, size

So I have been told on a few occasions that a keli that can hold a certain large amount of water does not require immersion before use. What is the minimal amount in gallons that would make t'vila unnecessary?

Comment: I've never heard of such a rule.

Answer (score 2):

What you were told on many occasions is incorrect.

The Binas Adam ([85/66](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=24603&st=&pgnum=58)) says specifically that holding a large amount such as 40 sa'ah is not a good reason to negate the need for tevila. (There is a discussion there concerning vessels which are attached to the ground.)

The Chachmas Adam there ([klal 73:13](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=24602&st=&pgnum=90)) is discussing large vessels and he rules they should get tevila.

His words are brought in the first Pischei Teshuva in [Yoreh Deah siman 120](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x4389).

The limud zchus for people who did not immerse the beer vats, which were the center of the discussion, was to assume the opinion that since there was still much prep needed to make the beer drinkable after removing the beer from the vats, tevila was not needed. But the preferable option is to drill a hole in the vat to make it unusable and have a Jewish person fix it.

Comment: when you say beer vats what does that mean? Are we talking about the vessels in which the liquid that becomes beer(the wort) is heated in, the fermenting vessels, or both?

Comment: He didn't specify but since he mentioned boiling, I'm assuming he is talking about boiling the wort for two reasons. Fermentation is not done at a boiling temperature and by the time it's fermented it's not missing any large process in order to drink.

Comment: I don't see boiling in the answer, fermentation is done in cold temperatures with a few exceptions but even then doesn't go above 80 df, after fermentation the beer still goes through additional changes when it is either bottled or kegged. The final product that is drunk is often very different from how it is coming out of the fermenter.  The primary cause for this being a resting period in which the beer conditions in the bottles or kegs.

Comment: also if a change in the vessel is all that is needed. wouldn't attaching the valves , sight glass and other connections for transferring wort and hot water be sufficient?

Comment: I didn't mention boiling in the answer as that wasn't the main point. See the link to Chayei Adam provided. The change after fermentation is not a BIG change. It doesn't change it from inedible to edible. Attaching any piece which plugs up a hole which if left open would render the device useless would suffice.